# Can I use two different routers on a desktop and laptop

Tags: router

I have an HP desktop and a Lenovo laptop, both 64bit and both on Windows 10. At present I am using a Huwaei 553 router, supplied by my ISP, this is connected by wireless to the laptop and by power adapters to the desktop which is not fitted with a wireless card. This router is also connected to a smart TV by ethernet.
I also have a Netgear N600 router which I would like to use solely on my desktop and leave the Huwaie for the laptop. Would this be possible without conflict of any kind. The desktop would remain on ethernet all the time. My question is simply whether I  can do this or not. I t seems a shame to have this excellent router lying around doing nothing. Any advice would be very much appreciated. I have been using computers for some years now and although not a geek am not an amateur. Please keep any advice in simple terms, thank you.

Comment: There is no real advantage doing what you ask.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this configuration will improve network performance if several machines are connected to each router when compared to the performance if switches were used instead. If there are 4 machines on router A, and 5 machines on router B, assuming A and B are connected, traffic between machines on B only would be faster for not having to go via A. It's a fairly specific case, but it does scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as pointed out, it is important to know why you wish to use two routers.

Using equipment for the sake of it not sitting idle will add complexity to your network, and will potentially cause issues with your configuration.

It is perfectly possible to use two routers on the same connection. Commonly, this would be used to allow a network to be shared around a larger building while using only one internet connection.

You can also use a second router in Access Point mode to allow a machine with no wifi connection to access the broadband line through an Ethernet cable.

As has been mentioned in comments, using multiple routers will make your network more complicated, and will potentially introduce problems.

It is however very possible, and there are several cases where it can be a usable solution when you need to expand a network.

If you simply wish to know how this can be achieved, it is outlined below.

***Routing***

For the sake of this example, Router A is connected to the broadband connection, and Router B is connected to Router A.

So long as Router A and Router B have different IP addresses, they can exist on the same network with no difficulty.

When connecting via a computer attached to Router B (through Ethernet, or WiFi if the computer supports it), any connections will be routed to the outside world via Router A, and returning connections will be routed back to the machine attached to Router B using Router A as the access point.

***Advantages/Disadvantages***

If you are using only one computer attached to the N600, you will see very little advantage over using only the one machine.

You mentioned that your desktop machine does not have a WiFi adapter.

If you connect the N600 to the Huwai via WiFi, and use the N600 as an access point, you can connect to the N600 from your desktop machine via Ethernet cable.
This will allow your desktop machine to connect to your main network from another location, using the WiFi to bridge the two routers.

N.B. - For the sake of completeness, I should point out that technically, using the N600 as an access point is not the same as bridging the two networks. The differences would take some time to explain, and I do not feel that adding them here will add any real value to this response, nor answer your question in any more detail.
If you would like the know the differences between AP mode and network bridging, please let me know and I shall expand on this answer.

***Connecting your modem to the broadband connection***

Comments posted below mention that the Netgear N600 does not have a modem.
This is in fact wrong.

There are several versions of the N600, some containing a modem and some not.

***If your ISP provides a connection through ADSL***

If you own a version of the N600 which is equipped with a modem, you have the choice of connecting your N600 directly to the line, or to use the existing Huwai unit.

There are pros and cons of each option.

Using the N600 will mean that you are able to make use of a router which (from your original question) you seem to favour.

It would mean however that you would have to configure your connection settings such that the N600 can be connected to your ISP.

These settings should have been provided by your ISP when you registered.
If you do not have these settings to hand, you can request them by contacting your ISP.

***If you connect via cable***

If your N600 is a cable only router, you will only be able to use it if your broadband connection is provided by a cable line.

If your N600 is equipped with a modem, it can be operating in either ADSL or Cable mode.

You will need to configure the operating mode in the Netgear Genie software to use Cable if you are connecting through a cable connection.

***Once you have chosen your main router***

One of the routers must connect to your net connection.

As you mentioned that the Huawai is supplied by the ISP, it is likely already configured with your connection details.

If this is the case, it will be a more simple process to use this router as your main router, and to run the N600 in AP (Access Point) mode.

***Connecting the N600 as an Access Point***

The following link describes setting AP mode on the N600.

http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20927/~/how-do-i-change-my-netgear-router-to-ap-mode-after-i%E2%80%99ve-already-run-setup%3F

I am unable to suggest how to use the Huwai router as an access point, as I have never personally owned one, although Huwai usually have fairly decent documentation.

The user manual for the HG533 is located here:
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/768803/Huawei-Echolife-Hg553.html

Comment: Curious why you've stated the ISP router has to be the main router? I have always used my own router and the ISP one sits in a cupboard in case the ISP wants it back :)

Comment: @Alex its a bad assumption. An ISP always provides a router, but most of the time, its just as a service because nowadays there are more than one device in the network, and they advertise: we give you a router for free, which has become so standard, that by default most ISP's give a router too. The question is, if the router has a build in modem too or not. If this is the case, then the other router must either also have a build on modem or will have to work in conjunction with the first router. I googled the Huwai 553 and it IS a modem/router while the N600 isn't. So both have to be used.

Comment: @Jonno Googling up both routers show that one has a MODEM while the other hasn't. So in this case it is a requirement to have both if you want to use the N600. But I agree, just assuming both are needed is bad.

Comment: I still think the best answer would be: just only use the huawai one, but if you want to use the N600 then both have to be used. But in a situation where a separate modem is in place, even if the OP says it as: I want to use both because I think the one from the ISP is required, you still should make sure the ISP one really is required. If it isn't then don't answer this part. It is this kind of support that people like OP need. People with insufficient knowledge make assumptions and then search for the wrong feedback.

Comment: @LPChip I've removed previous comments as they were verging on ranting. I do not agree that I should quiz OP on whether the ISP provided router is needed. OP asked a direct question, and I answered it. I included more detail, but this is likely more than OP needs. From the question, I inferred the structure of the network OP is aiming to use. OP asked if this can be done, and it can. Succinct support answers are better than rambling ones. Source: 12 years as a software developer, with 3 years of that working in support development.

Comment: @Alex I understand. My experience comes from 10 years being a Network-/ system administrator and 1 year of a sales man. One thing I learned is that a customer/client who asks for help usually doesn't ask why they need something. They just first thought of a solution then need help implementing that solution. Everytime one of my customers asks for this, I ask why they want it. About 60% of the time, I end up supplying a much better solution and they're happy I didn't blindly helped them with their original plan.

Comment: Also one other thing I miss that you should add: You cannot use the N600 router as a wifi receiver to link to the huwai network. OP might be thinking of doing that.

Comment: If the N600 is run as a repeater, it will connect to the huwai via wifi, and allow ethernet connection to the router. It seems that Netgear have reused the N600 name a number of times for several routers, access points and range extenders so its difficult to know what OPs unit can actually be configured to do.